# Ffmpeg. How to replace black bars by zoomed image

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, crop

In some videos there zoomed part of the same video instead of black bars.
Like this one:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your final canvas resolution is WxH, then you would run

```
ffmpeg -i video -filter_complex "[0]scale=W:H,boxblur=15:15,setsar=1[bg];[bg][0]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Comment: I can't understand how to use it: I'm getting wrong parameters error, could you explain better, in instance about w and h.

Comment: You should replace W and H with the actual numbers for output width and height. The first filter rescales the input to WxH and blurs it. Then the original unscaled input is overlaid on top.

Comment: I'm getting errors: `Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument`. Log file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QDbe115rjPTtcixXtQzm4qUb3Qx5S3FU

Comment: Remove `-c:a copy`

Comment: I had to replace `-c:a copy` with `-strict -2` (ffmpeg 2.8.14). I think you should edit your command accordingly.

Comment: You're using a very old version. `-strict -2` hasn't been required since 3.0. Current ver is 4.0.1